# import a folder with multiple .csv files and manipulate all dataframe at once in R

Tags: r, import, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a folder with 100 different .csv files. Not all files are containing the same number of variables (different structure) so I am trying to import them all at once and ( create separate data frame for each csv) then standardize dataframes by adding a new column or convert date column from character to date and export them at once again in the end. here is my try, it will work an read all the csv as a separate data frame

```
setwd(C:/Users/...)
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for(file in files)
{
  perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
  assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
    read.csv(paste(path,file,sep="")))
}
```

However, when I adding `mutate` to `assign` function to add a new column for instance , script will run but will not add any column! What I am missing here? My aim is add/manipulate some variables and export them again , preferably within tidyverse

```
for(file in files)
{
  perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
  assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
    read_csv(paste(path,file,sep="")),
    mutate(. , Heading = "Data"))
}
```

## Example

```
df1 <- structure(list(datadate = structure(c(17927, 17927, 17927, 17927, 
17927, 17927), class = "Date"), parent = c("grup", "grup", 
"grup", "grup", "grup", "grup"), ads = c("P9", 
"PS8", "PS7", "PS6", "PS5", "PS5"), chl = c("PSS9", 
"PSS8", "PSS7", "PSS6", "PSS5", "PSS5"), 
    average_monthly = c(196586.49, 289829.43, 
    1363529.14, 380446.43, 147296.09, 948669.38), current_month = c(987118.82, 
    1682872.03, 4356755.73, 2225040.29, 922506.21, 5756525.08
    ), current_month_minus_1 = c(585573.1, 
    635763.37, 6551477.37, 818531.11, 255862.51, 1832829.99), 
    current_month_minus_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2<-
  structure(
    list(
      network = c("STAR", "NPD", "GMD"),
      datadate = structure(c(18259, 18259, 18259)),
      brand = c("grup", "GFK", "MDG"),
      average_weekly = c(140389.14,
                                           10281188.25, 172017.39),
      last_week_avg = c(89303.07,
                                         6918460.99, 110594.64),
      last_week_1_minus_avg = c(141765.83,
                                                 10248501.1, 222484.9),
      last_week_2_minus_avg = c(138043.53,
                                                 9846538.57, 164185.21)

    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L)
  )
```

Comment: `for` loops and `assign` are usually considered a bad design in `R`, especially if you put the `tidyverse` tag to your question. Have you considered using `purrr`?

Comment: Also, as @hello_friend wrote, the merging will depend on your data. Could you give a short example (using `dput` preferably) of some files that have different column sets?

Comment: @DanChaltiel I have added some examples. I donot want to merge my data frame, I just want to standardize files to feed it into another system that accepts csv only in specific format

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution to read the files into a list, the changes required to merge them depend on your data:

```
# Store a scalar of the path containing the csvs: 

example_dir <- "C:/Users/Example_Dir"

# Create a vector of the csv paths: 

files <- file.path(example_dir, list.files(example_dir, pattern = ".*.csv"))

# Create an empty list the same length as the number of files: 

X <- vector("list", length(files))

# Iterate through the files and store them in a list:

X[] <- lapply(seq_along(files), function(i){

    data.frame(read.csv(files[i]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the design of your code, it seems that you are using `mutate` the wrong way.

In your code, you are placing the `mutate` call as the 3rd argument of the `assign` function, which should be the position (the environment of your variable).

What you'd really want to write is this:

```
assign(
  gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
  read_csv(paste(path,file,sep="")) %>% 
    mutate(Heading = "Data"))
}
```

If you are not familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), I suggest that you read some tutorials like the [`dplyr` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html#piping) which has a paragraph about it.

This code means: assign to a variable named after the `gsub` call the dataframe read from the csv, after mutating it to add the `Heading` column.

But, as in `hello_friend`'s answer, I urge you to rethink your design to work with lists rather than a bunch of variables. For this, the `tidyverse` way is to use the [`purrr` package](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions)

Comment: thanks @DanChaltiel , I am familer with purrr but       ```list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
      map_dfr(~read_csv(.) , .id = "Data" )´´´ shows an error about one variable in one csv file can't be converted from numeric to character. I couldn't find a way to skip parsing that specific variable in that specific data frame yet

Comment: If this happens in only one variable in one csv file, then it is maybe worth figuring out what is the problem: which variable, in which CSV? And what about `list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>% map_dfr(~read_csv(.) %>% mutate(Heading = "Data"))`?